# Data coming from web serial api is garbled

Tags: javascript, serial-port

When retrieving data from a balance using webserial api. I am getting the following

`SԬ-000��.96���`

When I should be getting
`ST,-00027.96  g`

I am opening the port with the following

```
await port.open({ baudRate: 2400, databits: 7,  stopbits: 1, parity: "none", flowControl: "none"});
```

and reading the data

```
const readerData = await this.reader.read();
var datavalue = (new TextDecoder("utf-8")).decode(readerData.value);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am pretty sure it used to work (although I could be wrong). Certainly the api changed recently to change the parameter baudrate to baudRate so not sure if something else changed at the same time.

Comment: The *"garbled"* data is typical for mismatched baudrate and/or misconfigured serial ports.  You need to verify that the device is actually transmitting at 2400 7N1, which is an uncommon configuration for modern equipment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice sawdust.

I used to use even parity and it worked. I assume there was an update to the api in December. If I use even parity now I get S��0�� ��;�� the first time I try to get something and then after that I get "ParityError: A parity error has been detected."

If I connect the application 232key up to the port it picks up the correct value with 2400 7E1 and it also does for 2400 7N1 so it must be doing something tricky.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmmm, in order to get this to work I had to set the parity to none and then remove the parity bit before decoding it. 

const readerData = await this.reader.read();
const clearMask = ~(1 << 7);
for (var i = 0; i < readerData.value.length;i++) {

 readerData.value[i] = readerData.value[i] & clearMask;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a tested answer as I have no way of reading a serial port with actual data coming in.

However, looking at the characters that have been read correctly and those that haven't there is consistency.

Those that have been read correctly will not have a parity bit set (should there be one) and those that have been read incorrectly will have a parity bit set.

for example:
lowercase g in ASCII is octal 147 - 01100111 in binary - an odd number of bits set
uppercase S in ASCII is octal 123 - 01010011 in binary - an even number of bits set

The suspicion is therefore that different character codings are being used, particularly as there appears to be a merging of the T and , to give a character.

So, is parity being set on the serial device now but not being taken into account when reading the characters for example? Is some sixteen bit encoding being looked for or...

Sorry I cannot investigate further. At least try reading with the parity bit set rather than not as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

So I missed the other changes to the api.

databits and stopbits also changed their capitalisation.
they are now dataBits and stopBits.